# Why are async/await allowed inside the domain model of DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, separation-of-concerns

I am trying to challenge my understanding of DDD by pushing it to the extreme.
My question is not about a specific practical use case.
Rather my question is an abstract one related to DDD in general.
Therefore, I do not have any source code to share but thoughts to discuss.

The domain model should be isolated from any infrastructure concern.
However, we still need a programming language to write the domain model.
Some constructs of the programming language of choice are more revealing of the underlaying runtime mechanics than others; for example, concurrency constructs like async/await and other similar ones.

Why are such constructs allowed in the domain model since they address a non-domain concern, i.e. infrastructure performance?
If we ask a domain expert, he/she does not usually have a domain concept that talks about concurrency per se; although, they may have time expectations or constrains.
If async/await are allowed, why not other constructs like SIMD?

How about pub/sub-like constructs since we do have domain events?
How about LINQ-like constructs and libraries?
What if the domain model provided their interface/function types and delegated their implementation to the infrastructure so it becomes implementation agnostic?
However, the interface/function types are still infrastructure revealing, i.e. you can still tell a lot about the infrastructure just by looking at the interface/function types.

My general question is: what is the criteria by which we can identify if something is allowed in an assumed ideal domain model or not?

Comment: `however, we still need a programming language to write the domain model.` you answered yourself.  Circumventing programming langue features for the sake of some theory is braindead dogmatism at its finest. We don't programme for the love of the art. We still have to be practical. Practical > any software engineering theory.

Comment: Why do we allow concrete data types in the domain model? no domain expert will ever say "this is a HashSet"

Answer (score 6):

[Functions can be red or blue](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/). Which color they are determines how they are called. An async/await function call has a different return type than a non-async function, because the value of an async function is delayed until some unknown future date. The `await foo()` syntax for calling these functions cleans up your code, but causes a ripple effect for callers that trickles up the call stack.

Even though your domain model does not rely directly on, say, a class that connects to a MySQL database, it does rely on interfaces which are ultimately implemented by real infrastructure classes that need to connect to a database, web API or call out to the file system. Due to performance or concurrency issues outside the scope of pure business rules, this changes how you call out to those infrastructure classes.

Consider a repository interface. It needs to return some collection of objects. This interface lives alongside your domain classes, but is implemented by a concrete class in your infrastructure layer. This concrete class must talk to a database. Developers (not business people) decided that an async call is justified to retrieve this data. Instead of your repository interface returning a `Collection<Foo>` object, it returns a "future" or "promise" — an object used to resolve the return value at some future date. In C#, for example, this changes the signature of your repository interface from `Collection<Foo>` to `Task<Collection<Foo>>`, where the "Task" object is a promise for a future value.

This demand from the infrastructure layer does trickle up the callstack and affect the signature of your repository interface defined in your domain model. This is simply a technical constraint placed on your domain model by the language that is implementing the domain model.

That said, you can certainly `await` a function that does not do anything asynchronous, but you cannot call an asynchronous function and get its return value synchronously.

You haven't made the domain model impure from a business standpoint. Not every technical detail needs to be a valid business concept. The important separation between domain model and infrastructure is loose coupling between infrastructure classes and domain classes. How you call a function is irrelevant to the business concepts your domain model embodies.

Answer (score 4):

**Concurrency is a concept which can be utilized at different levels of abstraction** - not only for "low level performance optimization", but also for modeling certain requirements at the domain level.

So what you wrote here

> If we ask a domain expert, he/she does not usually have a domain concept that talks about concurrency per se

is missing the fact that there are a lot of domains where concurrency matters, and where modeling it by using async/await is a reasonable approach. Some examples:

- almost any time-based simulation requires concurrency
- computer games
- controller software for machines with different moving parts
- monitoring software for vehicles

Even my personal GPS or smartphone serve as examples. Both contain several sensors, where aggregating the measurements into a single display in certain applications is an inherently concurrent operation.

To be fair, there are also cases where concurrency and parallelization are only used for performance optimization at a lower level of abstraction, sometimes "low enough" to be just an implementation details. A synchronous domain operation might start several asynchronous ones in parallel, waits until they are all completed and then return the aggregated results. That's what SIMD is usually used for - optimization by parallelization at a low level of abstraction.

Moreover, there are indeed scenarios where even high-level concurrency constructs can be kept out of the domain model by using infrastructure support. For example, multi-user access to transactional databases don't necessarily require async/await in the domain model. And for massive parallel tasks, [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) frameworks are popular, where the concurrent execution is left to the framework. Still, the latter requires domain models and their operations to be structured in a special way, separated into map and reduce operations. So this kind of infrastructure will "leak" into the domain interface.

In short, generally "forbidding" async constructs at the domain level for any kind of domain makes IMHO no sense. The fact not every domain really needs them does not mean they are obsolete or unnecessary for any other domain.

I also invested some thoughts into your final more general question:

> what is the criteria by which we can identify if something is allowed in an assumed ideal domain model or not?

I think we should stay pragmatic here: when "something" turns out to be useful for modeling real-world domains, with no obvious simpler alternative, then we should allow it - if it, however, complicates the understanding or the implementation in our target environment, then we should restrict the usage. But of course, this will depend a lot on the specific domain and context. If in your specific situation putting some restrictions on the usage of certain modeling elements helps to keep things simple, then go ahead. There is no "one-size-fits-all" approach to domain modeling.

Comment: also any form or seat reservation or sale (e-commerce) of a limited supply

Comment: @Rad80: yes, but those are examples where the concurrency is usually handled by database transactions, which don't require multithreading at the domain modeling level.

Answer (score 3):

Async/await is not inherently indicative of the underlying infrastructure. Quite the opposite, in fact.

Async/await makes it so that you no longer have to be aware of what the underlying infrastructure is. Async-friendly code can run on a single threaded machine, or a multithreaded one; one with IO calls (which warrant awaiting) or without IO calls (where awaiting is unnecessary but not obstructive either), ... It will work in all circumstances.

The problem is one of human perception on what is "the default way" of doing things.

We didn't use to have async/await, so it feels like implementing it now is doing something *extra*, and because of that we're often only doing it when it directly benefits us to do so.
From that perspective, using async/await "reveals" that we're benefiting from doing so, i.e. that we've got things worth await (which tends to mean IO dependencies).

Instead, async/await should be considered the default implementation. It's just what you do, regardless if/how you end up integrating external IO into your system or not.
From *that* perspective, using async/await is the agnostic way of doing things, which is precisely the principle on which domain logic is founded.

In a parallel universe where we would've started with async execution and only later implemented synchronous execution, someone would be asking why the domain would ever use synchronous syntax because it reveals that the underlying infrastructure does not need asynchrony.

Answer (score 1):

*Design is what we do when we want to get more of what we want than we would get by just doing it.* -- Ruth Malan

---

> Why are such constructs allowed in the domain model since they address a non-domain concern, i.e. infrastructure performance?

Because Eric Evans is "not your real dad."  There are no prizes to be won by writing code simply to satisfy DDD authorities.

The "domain model" pattern is *just a pattern*: a common way of doing things that we expect to be adjusted according to the forces acting in the context where we find it.

And there are properties that we might reasonably elevate above "expresses the pattern in its ideal form" -- like *legibililty*.

---

As programmers, it's common to discover that the abstractions we are using leak.

> All non-trivial abstractions, to some degree, are leaky. -- [Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/)

To some extent, the fiction of the domain model pattern is that all of the information we need is right here, that the copy of the information we have here is the authoritative copy, and that we have exclusive access to it.

But the reality may be that the authoritative copy of the information is somewhere else, or that it is not always available, or that we don't have exclusive authority over it, and so on.

If we are going to produce correct, robust programs, we have to interface with reality.

So what we're really thinking about here is how much mixing should we have between our idealized code and our reality code?

Now, there are some really interesting patterns for separating idealized code and reality code.  I recommend reviewing:

- [Async Injection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsavoQWAVqM), Mark Seemann
- [Building Protocol Libraries the Right Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cC3_jGwl_U), Cory Benfield

But here's the thing - those patterns are only good or bad to the extent that they *server the programmers who are actually working in the code*

> The code works for me, I don't work for the code. The packaging works for me, I don't work for the packaging. The testing works for me, I don't work for the testing. And yes, the process works for me, I don't work for the process. -- [GeePaw Hill](https://twitter.com/GeePawHill/status/1578445082893713422)

So it's *allowed* because its the right choice to make when it best serves the needs of the programmers in their own context (which includes their own development and skill level).